# perl error in svn_load_dirs.pl

Tags: perl, svn, macos

I want to manage vendor branches in svn using the svn_load_dirs.pl script.

When I execute this script on my Mac OS X 10.5, perl  v5.10.1 (*) built for darwin-multi-2level
I get he following error message:

> Argument "2.07_02" isn't numeric in subroutine entry at /usr/local/bin/svn_load_dirs line 22.

What does this mean and is this harmful?

Answer (score 2):

To understand Perl messages, you can look them up in [perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

> Argument "%s" isn't numeric%s
>
> (W numeric) The indicated string was
>   fed as an argument to an operator that
>   expected a numeric value instead.

Since this message is classified as a Warning, it may not be harmful.  But, it is worth investigating.  Since I do not have access to the `svn_load_dirs.pl` script, could you please update your Question with the 1st 22 lines of the script?